# Can't import sys class from sys library

Tags: python

I want to import only argv and executable functions from sys libray.

So I used from and import to specify those functions as so:-

```py
from sys import argv
from sys import executable
```

But after that I get an error that 'sys' is undefined so I added:-

```py
from sys import sys
```

but I get that sys is not member of sys, but how? if there is no class named sys' in sys library so how we for example use sys.executable() ?

Comment: Just do `import sys` and then `sys.executable()`. Doing "nested" imports is for the convenience. It's not THE syntax. You can also do `from sys import executable` then `executable()` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
from sys import argv
from sys import executable
```

you use `argv` `executable` directly instead of `sys.argv` `sys.executable`. The latter case is for

```
import sys
```